# Configure HTTP query-length for JBOSS eap 7.1

Tags: java, jboss, jboss-eap-7

I have some problem with migration from JBOSS eap 6.4 to JBOSS eap 7.1. 
I need to configure HTTP threads. In JBOSS eap 6.4 I had the next configuration:

```
<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:threads:1.1">
        <thread-factory name="HTTP-factory" group-name="http-executor" thread-name-pattern="HTTP-%t" priority="5"/>
        <bounded-queue-thread-pool name="http-executor">
            <queue-length count="4000"/>
            <max-threads count="1000"/>
            <keepalive-time time="30" unit="seconds"/>
        </bounded-queue-thread-pool>
        <bounded-queue-thread-pool name="http-executor-auth">
            <queue-length count="0"/>
            <max-threads count="1"/>
            <keepalive-time time="30" unit="seconds"/>
        </bounded-queue-thread-pool>
    </subsystem>
```

In JBOSS eap 7.1 module jboss:domain:threads was deleted and information about HTTP threads was moved to jboss:domain:io module. I try to configure it but I have some problems with configuring query-length. 
Now I have next configuration for JBOSS eap 7.1:

```
<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:io:2.0">
        <worker name="default" task-keepalive="30000" task-max-threads="1000"/>
        <buffer-pool name="default"/>
    </subsystem>
```

In RedHat documentation and [examples](https://access.redhat.com/solutions/2739801) I can't find needed information.

Maybe someone can help me configuring HTTP threads correctly.

Thanks.

Comment: Does it have a limit on it? Is it truncating your URLs and if so at which character number?

Comment: Yes, we need to set limit on queue length if all threads are busy at this moment. If count of one-off requests is greater than max-threads+query-lengths JBOSS 6.4 automatically reject request. And I need to configure the same behavior on JBOSS 7.1

Answer (score 0):

The default web container for EAP7 is **Undertow**. All the listeners in Undertow use a default worker which is provided by the IO subsystem. This worker instance manages all the listeners (AJP/HTTP/HTTPS) threads. You can can configure accordingly the worker's behaviour via the following attributes:

```
io-threads

stack-size

task-keepalive

task-max-threads
```